# POSTFIX / DOVECOT: limit the number of connections per user per minute

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I have a virtual user that checks his mails every minute per imap, using 4 phones and 2 laptops and a tablet.

how can I limit the connections per user? I do not want to limit the connections per IP.

Comment: Does this cause a real problem? Even an old Raspberry Pi should be able to handle seven connections and more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I think You have to change the dovecot configuration. In /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf look for this:

> mail_max_userip_connections

Change as you need. You cannot permit one job, because the clients program settings responsible for the mail check interval.

Comment: if I change this setting, then I restrict a residential school with 100 user who want to check the email from the same residential school ip. Because they all use the same IP.